# Elevating permissions with a different AD account

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am looking to create an AD account with local administrator group membership on some of our user computers (as they're developers and need full admin priviledges) but this account should not be able to be logged into, just used to elevate permissions.

I have tried a Group Policy to "deny log on locally", "user must require smart card to log on", "logon hours set to denied" but all of these disables the account from elevating permissions.

Is there a simple way to create an Active directory account which is a member of the local administrator group on that computer, but cannot be logged into, just used to elevate permissions?

Comment: There is no supported way of doing this.  The Windows security model doesn't distinguish between logging into a GUI session and any other interactive logon.  That said, you could probably do something like denying the account access to explorer.exe or one of the other executable files critical to the GUI logon procedure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a way to do this. Currently done with a batch file applied through logon script GPO.